# Sourcesafe checks out Control files, but makes no changes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

I have a problem using Sourcesafe in VS2008.

When I open certain controls in VS2008, I get an odd sequence of events;

- The files are checked out of sourcesafe (MyControl.cs, MyControl.designer.cs, and MyControl.resx)
- Visual Studio displays a dirty flag for the file (* after the filename)
- When I save the changes and diff the files, I cannot detect any changes.

Does anyone have an idea why VS might be making this 'null change' to my file, and how I might be able to stop it doing so?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this off and on for a bit and I was wondering if it could be something to do with font scaling? If someone using the form has large fonts turned on then that might alter it in a subtle and non-obvious way.